# Preg replace can not replace this tag?

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I am using this code to remove everything between this tag,however I can't make it happen.
What am I missing here?

```
$str ='<tr class="main_row pc">
    <td class="details">
        <a href="./view/4135660/"><span class="p_t">Fiat Cinquecento </span></a>
        <a class="info" href="./view/4135660/">(Info)</a><br>
        <div class="attribs">16345, <span class="p_l">Blue</span>, Phone 6914576304
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>';


$str = preg_replace('#(<tr class="main_row pc">).*?(</tr>)#', '$1$2', $str);
```

Comment: Mistake #1: Using regexes to mangle HTML... don't do this. Use [DOM](http://php.net/dom) instead.

Comment: Regex is not safe or simple to use on HTML. Put it through a DOM parser.

Comment: what are you trying to replace? because that preg_replace is trying to find "#(<tr class="main_row pc">).*?(</tr>)#" as a literal string which doesn't exist in $str...

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @Edward I want to remove everything between this tag

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Use a proper HTML parsing module.** You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php or [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php) for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Comment: @AndyLester Ok i will not, the next time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `s` modifier so that `.` will match newlines:

```
$str = preg_replace('#(<tr class="main_row pc">).*?(</tr>)#s', '$1$2', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

While it is a bad idea like you've already been harped upon about in the comments, you need a [pattern modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). Specifically `s` to make `.` match newline characters. So:

```
preg_replace('#(<tr class="main_row pc">).*(</tr>)#s', '$1$2', $str);
```

Will do what you need, at least according to the above-posted code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `s` [PCRE](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) modificator in order to make the dots in your RegEx match newlines, too.